# PHP redirects to register.php after logging in

Tags: php

I am working on this **social media** website and after creating a header file, I created a `userLoggedIn` variable which I assigned it to the session variable I created in **login handler** page for username using if statement or else the page should redirect to registration page.

 
The problem is the **login** page doesn't redirect me to the **index** page even after inserting correct username and password
here are my header codes

```
<?php
  require 'config/config.php';
  if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
     $userLoggedIn =$_SESSION['username'];
  }
  else{
     header("Location: register.php");
  }
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked with "session_start();" is must be the start of the file?

Answer (score 1):

Try to check error log. If there is something like this:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent (output started at script:line).

If you get this error, you have 2 options:

1. If it's mistake or error, remove/fix that part of code.
2. If you want to keep it, then add `ob_start()` or `ob_flush()` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])){
    $userLoggedIn =$_SESSION['username'];
}
else{
    header("Location: register.php");
}
```